# How to constrain that the Python script can only be invoked with one of the optional arguments at a time

Tags: python, scripting, argparse

My goal is that no optional arguments can be used simultaneously, this means the script can be invoked with one of the options at a time only, here is my code in Python:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-a", help="List out all the hostnames", action='store_true')
parser.add_argument("-v", help="List out student information", action='store_true')
parser.add_argument("-d", help="List out all the qualified domain name")
parser.add_argument("-c", help="List out all the qualified IPV4", choices=['A', 'B', 'C'])
parser.add_argument("filename", help="dataset name")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

And also, how to create a customized output if the optional arguments are given beyond the choices (-a, -v,-d, -c) instead of using `args = parser.parse_args()` to show the default error

Thank you guys, I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

When this sort of behaviour is described in English, the expression "mutually exclusive" tends to pop up, and a quick look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion) confirms that Argparse has an `add_mutually_exclusive_group` method that looks useful.